# fullcalender not working Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not constructor

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm install [Fullcalender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started) with

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

and after install success.

I'm import css on file 
app.sass

```
//Calender
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
```

after that.
app.js

```
window.Calendar = require('@fullcalendar/core');
window.dayGridPlugin = require('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
window.timeGridPlugin = require('@fullcalendar/timegrid');
window.listPlugin = require('@fullcalendar/list');
```

and run command npm run watch

after install and import and run command success , I try use example from [this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/webpack-example)

but, this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not constructor

My code

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },
                defaultDate: '2018-01-12',
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: '2018-01-01',
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2018-01-07',
                        end: '2018-01-10'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2018-01-09T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2018-01-16T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Conference',
                        start: '2018-01-11',
                        end: '2018-01-13'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2018-01-12T10:30:00',
                        end: '2018-01-12T12:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: '2018-01-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2018-01-12T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Happy Hour',
                        start: '2018-01-12T17:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Dinner',
                        start: '2018-01-12T20:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: '2018-01-13T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2018-01-28'
                    }
                ]
            });

            calendar.render();
```

So, I try check my problem many many site but never find site example Laravel use npm install fullcalendar

I'm try check on console.log

[image]

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6 did you write `import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';` at the start of your script? If not then I think you have to write`var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar` - giving the full namespace of the class.

Comment: this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
        import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]
            });

            calendar.render();
        });

Comment: "Cannot use import statement outside a module" ...ok so you have to try my second suggestion instead. Did you do that? Here's an example of using it successfully: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOOzjXJ

Comment: As per full calender document https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals, you need to add HTML, Body in  <div id='calendar'></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my answer

```
//Calender

import * as Calendar from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

window.FullCalendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
window.timeGridPlugin = timeGridPlugin;
window.listPlugin = listPlugin;
window.interactionPlugin = interactionPlugin;
```